# Basic multivariate Factorization type question

Tags: polynomials, factoring, elementary-functions, completing-the-square

I came across this polynomial
$$
x^2 - 2kxy + ky^2 +d; \, k>0
$$
in some of my work and was wondering if there was a trick to coercing/factoring it into a polynomial of the form
$$
(x-x_0)^2-(y-y_0)^2+r
$$
for some $x_0,y_0,r \in \mathbb{R}$. I was thinking a completing the square type approach but embarrassingly enough I'm stumped.  All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 2nd equation doesn't has $xy$. So...

Comment: or do you mean $$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+r$$?

Comment: Set $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+r = x^2 - 2kxy + ky^2 +d$ and see what happens.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: As Takahiro Waki points out, the second expression doesn’t have an $xy$ “cross term,” so without also performing a change of variables, there’s no way to factor one into the other. If you set both expressions to zero, the first describes a family of rotated conic sections centered at the origin, while the second (for $r\lt0$) is a circle centered at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Change of variables is totally acceptable to me if a direct factorization is not possible as long as the new y is a function of the old y alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can coerce the polynomial into a nicer form through
$$x^2-2ky+k^2y^2-(k^2-k)y^2+d=(x-ky)^2-(k^2-k)y^2+d$$
And if we set $u=x-ky$, we have
$$u^2+(k-k^2)y^2+d$$
The substitution is necessary, since as stated in the comments, we cannot write it as 
$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+r$ because of the xy term.